# How to encode opus audiostream for Discord Voice Channel

Tags: python, discord, audio-streaming, opus

I going to code an Python Discord Music Bot with the official Gateway API from Discord. I already know how to connect, send heartbeats and so on. Now I am at that point, were I have an UPD Port and IP and an Opus Key for encoding.
The Discord Docs tell me the following: "Voice data sent to discord should be encoded with Opus, using two channels (stereo) and a sample rate of 48kHz. Voice Data is sent using a RTP Header, followed by encrypted Opus audio data. Voice encryption uses the key passed in Opcode 4 Session Description and the nonce formed with the 12 byte header appended with 12 null bytes to achieve the 24 required by xsalsa20_poly1305. Discord encrypts with the libsodium encryption library."
Like I said i already hav that key but I dont now how to go on. My Goal is to stream an Youtube song to an Discord Voice channel (I already know how to get the "real" youtube link to stream with).